# Select statement within a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have the following select statement that returns exactly what I want:

```
DECLARE @result varchar(max) = ''

SELECT @result += (result.Fullname + '<br/>') 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Fullname
FROM Providers 
WHERE Status='A') as result

select substring(@result, 0, len(@result) - 4)
```

The only problem is, I want the output from this query to be displayed as a column entry from a larger select statement.

Eg.

```
SELECT      
    Column AS [AColumnName],

    SELECT @result += (result.Fullname + '<br/>') 
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Fullname
    FROM Providers 
    WHERE Status='A') as result

    select substring(@result, 0, len(@result) - 4) as [LenderList]
FROM
 Table
```

But I am currently getting the error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
The error pointing to line 4

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need aggregate string concatenation in SQL Server.  There are already many answers on the subquery, but to save you the trouble:

```
SELECT Column AS [AColumnName],
       STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '<br/>' + Fullname
              FROM Providers 
              WHERE Status = 'A'
              FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
             ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'
                    ), 1, 5, ''
            ) as result
FROM Table;
```

The use of the type is important because your string has special XML characters.

Comment: This seems to work for me - thank you!
The only changes I had to make was to increase the character start to 5 to stop an errand > sign from appearing, and to make sure 'value' was in lower case, else it was throwing a ""VALUE" is not a valid function, property, or field." error.

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply run it in 2 statements?

```
SELECT @result += (result.Fullname + '<br/>') 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Fullname
     FROM Providers 
     WHERE Status='A') as result

SELECT      
    Column AS [AColumnName],
    substring(@result, 0, len(@result) - 4)
FROM Table
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to like having the select statements within the select statement - I am still getting the **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.** error

Answer (score 0):

Which Database? If you can use for xml, then something like...

```
select substring(a.innards, 0, len(a.innards) - 4) as [LenderList]
from 
(
    SELECT innards = STUFF(
        (SELECT DISTINCT Fullname + '</br>'
        FROM Providers
        WHERE [Status] = 'A'
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
        , 1
        , 0
        , '')
) a
```